# Issue about creating HTTPS Server and install local IPA on iOS 10

Tags: https, server, localhost, ios10, ipa

I'm developing an App which need to connect a SSL-VPN tunnel and fetch an enterprise IPA and install it on iOS device.

My App can call the SSL-VPN sdk and download the IPA file from the vpn-tunnel, but the iOS/AppStore installation-module cannot, so there is no way to install the plist and IPA file directly. So I got some open-source code to create a local https server (use my self-signed CA&SSL certificates), download the goal IPA and plist files previusly, then changed the URL contents of the plist to local path:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>items</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>assets</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>software-package</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>https://localhost:9999/XXX.ipa</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>full-size-image</string>
                    <key>needs-shine</key>
                    <false/>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>https://localhost:9999/logo.png</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>display-image</string>
                    <key>needs-shine</key>
                    <false/>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>https://localhost:9999/logo.png</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>metadata</key>
            <dict>
                <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                <string>com.XXX.XXX</string>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>software</string>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>XXX</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Also I placed a index.html in my local web folder:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>iPhone HTTPS Server Example</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<h1>Welcome to HTTPServer!</h1>


<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://localhost:9999/XXX.plist">Install App</a><br/>

</body>
</html>
```

After that I launched my App on my iOS device, use webview/safari to show index.html, (first of all: import my CA certificate and trust it), click the link and installed my local IPA app. **Everything run perfectly on iOS 8 and iOS 9.**

After the iOS 10 released, the issue came also.
On iOS 10, my App and the HTTPS Server can run correctly, but when I click the Install link, system show error popup: Cannot connect to localhost.

So I generated some SSL certificates (bound to the specified IP address) and did these test then:

**Test 1.** Launch my App on iOS 9 device, use the iOS 10 device to access the web page from iOS 9, click the link and install IPA on iOS 10, successfuly!

**Test 2.** Launch my App on iOS 10 device, use the iOS 9 device to access the web page from iOS 10, click the link and install IPA on iOS 9, successfuly!

**Test 3.** Launch my App on iOS 9 device, access the web page from local, click the link and install IPA locally, successfuly!

**Test 4.** Launch my App on iOS 10 device, access the web page from local, click the link and install IPA locally, FAILED! FAILED! FAILED!

What the hell is the reason, God Save Me!!!!!!!

I'm almost crazy, could anyone please help me, thanks a lot!

Comment: I did another test:
Test 5. Launch my App on one iOS 10 device, use another iOS 10 device to access the web page from the 1st iOS 10, click the link and install IPA on the 2nd device, successfuly!

So ... it looks like Apple prevent the system to install IPA from local network ...

Comment: Error log in system log:

... ... 

Sep 29 18:16:53 liuhm itunesstored[126] <Notice>: Could not load download manifest with underlying error: Error Domain=SSErrorDomain Code=107 "\M-f\M^W\240\M-f\M-3\M^U\M-h\M-?\M^^\M-f\M^N\M-%" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=\M-f\M^W\240\M-f\M-3\M^U\M-h\M-?\M^^\M-f\M^N\M-%}

... ...

Comment: U said that u have open source code that works in iOS 9. Could u share it please?

Comment: have you solved this?